# Why has xerces changed XMLCh to char16_t, can I change it back to wchar_t?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, xerces-c

We've been working with an old, pre-built version of Xerces 3.1.1 which has:

### 3.1.1: Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp

```
#ifdef _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#  define XERCES_XMLCH_T      wchar_t
#else
#  define XERCES_XMLCH_T      unsigned short
#endif
...
typedef XERCES_XMLCH_T              XMLCh;
```

Moving to use **vcpkg** it has installed 3.2.3 and we have compile errors because instead of `wchar_t` it is using:

### 3.2.3: Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp

```
#define XERCES_XMLCH_T char16_t
...
typedef XERCES_XMLCH_T              XMLCh;
```

We have *lots* of code making calls like `src.setEncoding(L"UTF-16");` which obviously leads to errors such as:

> void xercesc_3_2::InputSource::setEncoding(const XMLCh *const )':
> cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wchar_t [7]' to 'const XMLCh
> *const '

I'm not sure if Xerces has changed or if this is a result of vcpkg's default build settings. Is it possible to get it back to `wchar_t` (other than hacking sources), if so how? I am a total cmake noob unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, according to the [xerces-c docs](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html):

XMLCh type (UTF-16 character type):

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| -Dxmlch-type=char16_t | use char16_t (requires a C++11 compiler) |
| -Dxmlch-type=uint16_t | use uint16_t from or <stdint.h>, or another unsigned 16-bit type such as unsigned short if the standard types are unavailable |
| -Dxmlch-type=wchar_t | use wchar_t (Windows only) |

In **vcpkg**, this is partially exposed through **features**:

`vcpkg install xerces-c[xmlch-wchar]`   XMLCh type uses wchar_t